# Jekyll with kramdown: How to use <href> in table cell

Tags: html, jekyll, cells, kramdown

Using Jekyll with kramdown, how do I add a hyperlink (with target="_blank") to text within a table cell?

(I want to open a certain webpage when someone clicks text in a table cell.)

---

*Update*: As I was writing this question, I found the answer on another site.
But I decided to post the question anyway, because I will probably forget the answer and will come back to Stack Overflow someday to find it again.

The answer is: Just use a normal `<a href>` tag.

Here's an example of a one-column table that has a cell with a hyperlink:

```
Mounting Racks | 
-------------- |
<a href="http://somewebpage.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a> |
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Just use a normal `<a href>` tag.

Here's an example of a one-column table that has a cell with a hyperlink:

```
Mounting Racks | 
-------------- |
<a href="http://somewebpage.com" target="_blank">Click Me</a> |
```

PS I know it doesn't help my reputation to answer my own question, but I thought it might help others to see that the question has an answer.